# What pronoun do you use to say "My family. I love them" in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronombres

Vi un post de una amiga mía en Facebook. Era sobre su familia. Escribió algo como:

> mi familia (fotógrafo).

Entonces, escribió algo, pero no sé qué:

- las amo
- los amo
- la amo

Yo sé que es una palabra feminina, pero no estoy seguro de si hay que decir *las*, *los* o *la amo*. Como:

> My family. I love them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, you want to know what to pronoun to use when translating *My family. I love them*.

Since *familia* is a feminine, singular noun, the intuition makes us think that *la* should be the correct one:

> Mi familia. **La** quiero

However, this mentions family as a whole and you normally want to express the love for each and every member. For this reason, I do think that it is more idiomatic to use *los*:

> Mi familia. **Los** quiero

Which matches what you do in English (*My family* is singular, *I love them* uses the plural).

Comment: I forget where it was in the gramática (or DPD) that talked about this.  It mentioned the conditions under which one would (/could) have the apparent ungrammatical mismatch.

Comment: @guifa I found some references in the [gramática](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) around article 12.4, but could not find the exact one (it is a bit messy, since each result has a little screenshot of the book, it would be useful to have bigger sections).

Comment: if this answer resolved your doubt, please remember to mark it as 'answered' with the green check mark. @GinaAxella